# How to eliminate screen tearing in Ubuntu 16.04.02?

Tags: screen, tearing

I am getting relentless screen tearing in Ubuntu 16.04.02. It is especially noticeable in page scrolling in Chrome and in video playback. How do I eliminate this?

My machine has:

Intel Core i7 2nd Gen 2670QM

AMD Radeon HD 7690M XT

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the GPU on the 2670QM or the AMD GPU?

Answer (score 0):

Install compiz and open it (you can install it from software center),
- in your menu go to System/Preferences/CompizConfig Settings Manager
- enable Composite, Open GL and Work Arounds
(additionally you might also enable Animations to get some nice desktop effects)
- go to Composite and make sure "Detect Refresh Rate" and "Undirect Fullscreen Windows is checked" this should already fix most full screen tearing issues.

to remove all tearing go to Workarounds (you can search for it by typing it in the text field on the top left)
enable the options "Force complete redraw on initial damage" AND "Force full screen redraws (buffer swap) on repaint"

web browsers: You can disable "smooth scrolling" in chrome/chromium/firefox browsers (you can search on google) it will help to have better scrolling.

Video playback: Try different video players.